# Games Are Devillish

Tags: wordplay, poetry, video-games

Wonder if anybody can get this... (This is my first puzzle with this format; apologies if I made it too easy or hard.)

> My prefix will scare you,
>   My infix will restrict you,
>   And my suffix will uplift you.
>
> My prefix is a game object,
>   My infix is a game trigger,
>   And my suffix is loosely relative.

Comment: Do both paragraph lead to the same word or is the answer two words?

Comment: The same word! :)

Comment: Do you have a hint?

Comment: Unfortunately I have forgotten the answer to my own riddle - I will likely remember it once somebody gets it correct though lmfao.

Answer (score 3):

My guess:

Prefix:

> Di/Die (afraid to die, or die as in a game piece)

Infix

> Stop (as in restrict you or as in trigger stop)

Suffix

> ia/pia (ia as in to uplift you 'higher' or pia as in the loosely relative 'peer'

Full word:

> Distopia - an imagined state or society in which there is great suffering or injustice

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

> The Prefix is Di/Die

Because:

> 1) Death scares lots of people (thanatophobia) 
>  2) Die is the singular of Dice and is used commonly in board games